# cmd script from powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

At the end of a powershell script, i wanted to starta cmd script.
In order to proceed, i added this : `Invoke-Command cmd /c $destinationn\02_creation_de_repertoire.cmd`

Result :

```
Invoke-Command : Impossible de trouver un paramètre positionnel acceptant l'argument «
C:\Users\moamg\Desktop\SPO\02_creation_de_repertoire.cmd».
Au caractère C:\Users\moamg\Desktop\scripts_global\01_install_spo1.ps1:32 : 1
+ Invoke-Command cmd /c $destinationn\02_creation_de_repertoire.cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keCommandCommand
```

Any clue ?
I started ./FILE.cmd, or FILE.cmd from powershell, and it work. But in the script, it don't.

Comment: The version of `Invoke-Command` with the `-FilePath` takes its arguments as an array. So `Invoke-Command -filepath Path-To-Cmd 'arg1','arg2'.

Comment: When using a cmdlet always check [MS Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) and/or Get-Help *[cmdlet]*

Comment: You could try a plain `cmd.exe /c $destinationn\02_creation_de_repertoire.cmd` without the initial `Invoke-Command`

Answer (score 1):

The cmdlet excepts a script block:

```
Invoke-Command { cmd /c $destinationn\02_creation_de_repertoire.cmd }
```

Or explicitly:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { cmd /c $destinationn\02_creation_de_repertoire.cmd }
```

Comment: As an addition: the script must be enclosed in something, otherwise parameters for the script could be confused with parameters of Invoke-Command by the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Start-Process -FilePath $destinationn\02_creation_de_repertoire.cmd` instead.  Try `help Start-Process` from your command prompt for full syntax.